# A cookie issue started with the Instagram api. Something changed with the configuration and it has me baffled

Tags: html, jquery, cookies, instagram, samesite

The instafeed api stopped working on my site. The error I am getting is:

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://instagram.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Chrome changed something and I am trying to understand. Any help would be appreciated.

The site where I wrote this is here. http://galnova.com

```
  var accessToken = '271323200.1677ed0.0a4c06efd9474022b9c3eb47bccf5657'; // use your own token 713486902779818|vM5scnvKTkbBmLbsSgBTPVi3Gqs
    
  $.getJSON('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='+accessToken+'&callback=?',function (insta) {
    $.each(insta.data,function (photos,src) {
      if ( photos === 6 ) { return false; }
        var date = new Date(parseInt(this.created_time) * 1000);
         // template
      $(
          
        '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 grip_wrap flx gonzo">' +
        '<div class="grip_hang_topp"></div>' +
        '<div class="col grip flex_el flx_ex">' +
        '<a title="' + this.caption.text + '" class="fancybox zero lass"  data-fancybox="gallery1" data-caption="' + this.caption.text + '" href="' + this.images.standard_resolution.url + '">' +
        '<img src="' + this.images.standard_resolution.url + '" />' +
        '</a>' +
        '<div class="col coat2 truncate">' + this.caption.text + '</div>' +
        '<div class="row nill">' +
        '<span class="col-6 heart-wrap floated">' + '<i class="fa fa-heart">'+ '</i>' + this.likes.count +' <div class="summ">likes</div>'+'</span>' +
        '<span class="col-6 comment-wrap floated">' + '<i class="second fa fa-comment">'+ '</i>' + this.comments.count +' <div class="summ">comments</div>'+'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
    '<div class="row nill">' +
        '<span class="col-sm-12 check-wrap floated">' + '<i class="second fa fa-check">'+ '</i>' + 'Posted ' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear().toString().substring(2) +'</span>' +
    '</div>' +
        '<div><a href="http://galnova.com/insta.html"><button class="col-12 btn btn-outline-tertiary">UltraGallery <span class="fab fa-instagram"><\/span></button></a></div>' +
        '</div>' +
          
        '<div class="grip_hang_bott"></div>' +
        '</div>'

      ).appendTo('#instafeed');
    }); 
$(".grip").hover(function(e){
    "use strict";
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(window).width() > 991) {

        return false;
    }
});
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instagram Api has changed, read more about it [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)

Comment: I read through all of this. I still don't understand how to fix it is what I am saying. I don't know where to add code, if I need to generate something new or what.

Comment: There is no easy way. You need first to create facebook developer account then get token/ your app approved. There are some tutorials on YouTube. Days of easy embedding of Instagram pictures are over.

Comment: OK I started this process. I undertsand and thanks.